# Locking Cells based on value in cell in the column ahead of it

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am attempting to create an orderly serious of data validated cells. The idea is to utilize the worksheet to track the status of a list of projects. However the ideal scenario is that IF a cell preceding the next step equals a specific value it is unlocked and the user may proceed, if it is not, then they will be unable to select the cell. However I haven't the slightest clue how to tackle this as it could be task dependent as in, specific cells instead of entire rows and columns.

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Project 1 | Task Stat | Task Stat2 | Task Stat4 |
| ^ Task | ^ First cell value | ^ This cell locked unless column 2 = Value | ^This cell locked unless column 3 = Value |

Comment: Formula will not do this.  You will need vba in a Worksheet_Change event.

Comment: I'd assumed that much, but haven't the slightest clue as to where to start with VBA.

Comment: Where to start with VBA is off topic here.  This site is about helping overcome specific problems with existing code.

Comment: Just to get you started on [worksheet changes](https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/worksheet-change-event/), you may google more examples, just look for event changes and get familiar with it.